# Aux-like pattern for path dependent types?

Tags: scala, typeclass, type-level-computation, path-dependent-type

**Goal**: I would like to write

```
feedImplicitInstance[Cat](new CatFood())`
```

and have the same effect as

```
feedExplicitInstance(Cat.CatInstance)(new CatFood())
```

**How can I do that ?
Is it possible to do that at all ?**

This is what I tried (but it did not really work):

```
object DepType extends App{

  println("bla")

  def feedExplicitInstance[AnimalInstance]
      (animal:AnimalTypeClass[AnimalInstance])(food:animal.FoodThatAnimalLikes) = {
      animal.feed(food)
  }

 //  Does not compile:

  def feedImplicitInstance[AnimalInstance,Food](food:Food)
  (implicit animal:AnimalTypeClass[AnimalInstance],aux:Cat.Aux[Food,AnimalInstance]) = {
    animal.feed(food)
//    Error:(17, 17) type mismatch;
//    found   : food.type (with underlying type Food)
//    required: animal.FoodThatAnimalLikes
//    animal.feed(food)

  }
  feedExplicitInstance(Cat.CatInstance)(new CatFood())

}

trait Food{
  def eat():Unit
}

trait AnimalTypeClass [AnimalInstance] {
  type FoodThatAnimalLikes <: Food
  def feed(f:FoodThatAnimalLikes)=f.eat()
}

trait Cat

class CatFood extends Food{
  override def eat(): Unit = println("meow")
}

object Cat {
  type Aux[Food,Animal]= AnimalTypeClass[Animal] {type FoodThatAnimalLikes = Food}

  implicit object CatInstance extends AnimalTypeClass[Cat]{
    override type FoodThatAnimalLikes = CatFood
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we define `Aux` like this:

```
object AnimalTypeClass {
  type Aux[A, F] = AnimalTypeClass[A] { type FoodThatAnimalLikes = F }

  implicit object CatInstance extends AnimalTypeClass[Cat] {
    override type FoodThatAnimalLikes = CatFood
  }
}
```

We can then summon the right implicit typeclass via a method:

```
def feed[A, F <: Food](f: F)(implicit animalTypeClass: AnimalTypeClass.Aux[A, F]) = {
  animalTypeClass.feed(f)
}
```

And now this compiles and runs:

```
feed(new CatFood())
```

I changed the name of the generic type parameters a bit, but they're largely the same as in your example. Just note the implicit instance definition changes.

Comment: Wow, many thanks for the detailed answer, I will go through it in detail soon (and try to grasp it) - at the very moment things got a bit busy.

Comment: @jhegedus Sure thing. LMK if you have questions

Comment: I don't quite get what `implicit def feedImplicitInstance[A, F <: Food](...):Unit` is doing. I mean, it returns `Unit`, so how can it be used for anything ? It has nothing else but side effects. I am confused.

Comment: ^ what do you think about this ? @Yuvil

Comment: @jhegedus You're completely right. There's no need for it, as the `feed` method is almost identical.

Comment: Yes, I start to get it, this is really interesting approach, thanks !

Comment: So, my mistake was that I wrote `animal.feed(food)` instead of `aux.feed(food)`  in `feedImplicitInstance`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it makes more sense to put `Aux` in the `AnimalTypeClass` companion object, and switch the order of its type parameters. Though none of this is *required* to make it compile.

In order to enable your preferred calling convention of `feedImplicitInstance[Cat](new CatFood())` `feedImplicitInstance` is allowed to have only one type parameter. But `Food` must be a type parameter because forward references like `animal.FoodThatAnimalLikes` in parameter lists are not allowed, as you probably noticed yourself. That's why you needed the `Aux` in the first place. To reconcile those conflicting constraints, you should manually implement a sort of type parameter currying. That's what the `Feeder` class in the following complete example is for:

```
object DepType extends App {

  def feedExplicitInstance[AnimalInstance]
      (animal: AnimalTypeClass[AnimalInstance])(food: animal.FoodThatAnimalLikes) = {
      animal.feed(food)
  }
  class Feeder[AnimalInstance] { 
    def apply[F <: Food](food: F)(implicit animal: AnimalTypeClass.Aux[AnimalInstance, F]) =
      animal.feed(food)
  }
  def feedImplicitInstance[AnimalInstance] = new Feeder[AnimalInstance]

  feedExplicitInstance(Cat.CatInstance)(new CatFood())
  feedImplicitInstance[Cat](new CatFood())

}

trait Food{
  def eat(): Unit
}
class CatFood extends Food{
  override def eat(): Unit = println("meow")
}

trait AnimalTypeClass[AnimalInstance] {
  type FoodThatAnimalLikes <: Food
  def feed(f: FoodThatAnimalLikes) = f.eat()
}
object AnimalTypeClass {
  type Aux[A, F <: Food]= AnimalTypeClass[A] {type FoodThatAnimalLikes = F}
}

trait Cat
object Cat {
  implicit object CatInstance extends AnimalTypeClass[Cat]{
    override type FoodThatAnimalLikes = CatFood
  }
}
```

Comment: Jasper, to you as well, many thanks for your answer ! I will go through it soon (and try to grasp it), at the moment things got a bit busy and they distract me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using Yuval's answer, this is how my modified code looks like:

```
object DepType2 extends App{

  println("bla")

  def feedExplicitInstance[AnimalInstance]
  (animal:AnimalTypeClass[AnimalInstance])(food:animal.FoodThatAnimalLikes) = {
    animal.feed(food)
  }

  def feedImplicitInstance[AnimalInstance,Food](food:Food)
                                               (implicit animal:AnimalTypeClass[AnimalInstance],aux:AnimalTypeClass.Aux[Food,AnimalInstance]) = {
    aux.feed(food)

  }
  feedExplicitInstance(AnimalTypeClass.CatInstance)(new CatFood())
  feedImplicitInstance(new CatFood())

}

trait Food{
  def eat():Unit
}

trait AnimalTypeClass [AnimalInstance] {
  type FoodThatAnimalLikes <: Food
  def feed(f:FoodThatAnimalLikes)=f.eat()
}

trait Cat

class CatFood extends Food{
  override def eat(): Unit = println("meow")
}

object AnimalTypeClass {
  type Aux[Food,Animal]= AnimalTypeClass[Animal] {type FoodThatAnimalLikes = Food}

  implicit object CatInstance extends AnimalTypeClass[Cat]{
    override type FoodThatAnimalLikes = CatFood
  }
}
```

So I had to change `animal` to `aux` in `feedImplicitInstance` and `object Cat` into `object AnimalTypeClass` and now everything works fine.

Of course the original question was a little bit trickier:
How can I write `feedImplicitInstance[Cat](new CatFood())` ?

Jasper's answer is the answer for the original question. I have not understood his answer yet perfectly - I need to find some time to read carefully, hopefully very soon.